# How to manage single website with multiple database based on user's location

Tags: database

I am developing one website which promote local business. we will have separate domain for different country so I am thinking that I will have separate database for each country so that will be easy to manage. we have many features which require to signup/sign-in in app. after sign-in user can get points and based on that points user can get reward

Main Problem is that if user 1 belongs to INDIA then he will have a data for local market which means user can see all local business from INDIA, based on user activity he/she will get points, but suppose that user go to Dubai or any other country then we will have a separate database for that country so that user can see list of all business from that respective country but how to manage authentication & earning & reward for that user ?

I want a solution where user don't require signup/signin for different country & manage different earning points & rewards, user should be authenticated from same credentials, get reward anywhere from world & get earn point from any where in the world.

**We want to manage it country wide because there is no meaning to store all record in same database for all country because we will have a separate domain for each country.**

Comment: "Poor man's solution": user connects, authenticates on local database first.  If that does not work, send the login query to others.  If ok, continue on. That would force you to have a unique user id for all countries, no duplicates (could use email).  Just make sure communications are encrypted and you have encryption to only allow your application to call another one, and not any browser on the web!

Comment: Other solution: all sites redirect to a single "user management" site, which does the authorization, and keeps global data about users.  Your web sites updates that central repository.  You have to setup an SSO with a token that is valid on all sites, to support the multiple domains.